# Add and name a bookmark jprofiler

Tags: java, analysis, jprofiler, heap-dump

I can see the option to "Add Bookmark" in Jprofiler. I would like to name the bookmark. The bookmark should be in custom format. Example "100LoggedinUsers", "200LoggedinUsers". Looking at the bookmarks, I should be able to make sense as to why the bookmark was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In interactive mode, you can right-click an existing bookmark and change its name. If you use the API or a trigger action, you can specify a name when the bookmark is created.